# My firefox can't run java

Tags: java

I check this at: http://javatester.org/version.html

I already downloaded the latest SDK. It seems the issue is that

Java (TM) Platform SE 7 U5 10.5.1.255 has a warning that it has vulnerability and use with caution.

The thing is it's NOT disabled.

Also I already updated JDK to the latest version. I want to uninstall the plugin but there is no such option. I can only disable.

My other computer's firefox are doing fine.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have Java 7 Update 5 installed but "already downloaded latest SDK".  I suggest you use http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/javara-download/ to uninstall any version you have installed then install the current version.

Comment: There is a bug in firefox that says that if things went south I need to reinstall firefox. I don't bother. I just activate java when I need to.

Comment: Actually that's the issue. I installed the latest SDK and still have Java 7 Update 5 installed as plugin.

Comment: @JimThio You mentioned that your System is 64 bit. I hope you did download and installed the 32 bit Java SDK (x86) as Firefox is 32 bit. On a 64 bit OS, one needs to install both x86 and x64 bit Java.

Comment: firefox is a 32 bit apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Java is 1.7.0_11 i.e. Update 11. Even that has a [security vulnerability](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/Jan/142) and hence is disabled by default in Firefox (I think Firefox 17 started disabling unsafe plugins by default)

Try updating to [Java 7 Update 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html). Also once you update and open Firefox, if any site needs Java, a small red icon will come in the address bar. Just click to enable Java for that Firefox session. Else go to add ons manager and permanently enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the 32 bit Java, not the 64. You can have both. Firefox is one of the easier browsers to get Java working.
You want the JRE, currently 1.7.0_11.

Sometimes you must reinstall Firefox after upgrading your Java. For other tips, see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/firefox.html

Comment: My systen is 64 bits.

Comment: @JimThio - You should update the original question if thats the case.  Of course it really doesn't matter since if your using a 32-bit browser.